# Avro schema automatic publishing in spring

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

How to configure spring/kafka to automatically publish avro schemas to schema registry without need to publish records to corresponding topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry will only be interacted with when you pass data through a serializer which means you need to invoke a producer

Otherwise, you can import CachedSchemaRegistryClient or use the Registry maven plugin to register schemas without a producer, or just use direct HTTP requests

Comment: Thank you, I used KafkaAvroSerializer for just invoking serialize method with dummy objects, which registers schema.